# How do I cast a varchar to Bigint in DB2

Tags: db2, cast, string

I have a field which is `varchar(25)` and I need to create a `join` between that field and a field that is a `bigint`

So I guess I need to convert the field into bigint aswell but it's giving me some grief because one result has an alphabet in it. 
How do I make it ignore the alphabet so I can create a join.

I'm currently trying 
left join `cast(queens.studentid as bigint) = north.studentid`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may want to provide some sample data and desired outcome. Mentioning your DB2 version and platform won't hurt either.

Comment: Idea 1: cast the int to varchar instead. Idea 2: use `CASE` expression with (some complex) condition that checks that the varchar contains only digits: `CAST( CASE WHEN (...) THEN queens.studentid END as bigint) = north.studentid`

Comment: ypercube is absolutely right on both counts. A condition for checking the VARCHAR only contains digits which I've used in the past on DB2 is (hopefully I can remember this correctly!): `CASE WHEN TRANSLATE(my_string, '##########', '0123456789') = REPEAT('#', LENGTH(my_string)) THEN its_numeric ELSE its_not_numeric END` - this assumes '#' cannot appear in my_string - pick a suitable char otherwise